# Powershell DSC error: OperationStopped: Serialized XML is nested too deeply. Line 1, position 3459

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I created a very basic `DscResource` and it successfully running the `Get` method. For testing purposes I defined `Test` method like that:

```
[bool] Test() {
  return $true
}
```

but every time that I invoke this method running:

```
Invoke-DscResource ... -Method Test
```

the output is error:

```
OperationStopped: Serialized XML is nested too deeply. Line 1, position 3459.
```

but actually in `Event viewer` the operation completed successfully:

```
[
  {"time": "2024-02-06T13:03:11.076+02:00", "type": "verbose", "message": "[QUICK-DEV]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[VmFirewall]DirectResourceAccess]  "},
  {"time": "2024-02-06T13:03:11.155+02:00", "type": "verbose", "message": "[QUICK-DEV]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[VmFirewall]DirectResourceAccess] True in 0.0790 seconds."},
  {"time": "2024-02-06T13:03:11.155+02:00", "type": "verbose", "message": "[QUICK-DEV]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]    in  0.2200 seconds."}
]
```

Why this message `Serialized XML is nested too deeply` appear ? and what I can do about it ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today, Windows PowerShell 5.1 ships with [PSDesiredStateConfiguration v1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psdesiredstateconfiguration/?view=dsc-1.1), this mixed with the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_windows_powershell_compatibility?view=powershell-7.4) feature means that PowerShell 7 will attempt to use the compatibility session. The error is due to the session attempting to serialize/deserialize the return values for the DSC resource.

The options are to

- Update to [PSDesiredStateConfiguration v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psdesiredstateconfiguration/?view=dsc-2.0).
- Use the `WindowsPowerShellCompatibilityModuleDenyList` setting in PowerShell configuration file.
- Use the `DisableImplicitWinCompat` setting in PowerShell configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug in Powershell... Everything working as expected if I use Windows Powershell but it fails with error if I user Powershell Core.... So strange...